# How to find the end_date of django celery in Django?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have a chain like this:

```
 chain = file_transfer.s(password, source12, destination1) | save_db.s(request.user.id, basename, extension, servername, start_date1, datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
```

While calling `save_db.s`, I want to call to get the `end_date` that's why I used `datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)` to calculate the end_date. The problem is that it calculates date when the task is initiated. How can I get the end_date of each task and save the end_date in a database for later use. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remember `save_db.s` will get result of `file_transfer.s` as first arg. Therefore you can return result from `file_transfer.s` as tuple with datetime.

Example:

> from django.utils.timezone import now
>
> ```
> def file_transfer(...):
>     ...
>     return (now(), ...)
>
>
> def save_db(end_date, ...):
>     ...
> ```